# Find all IP columns that occures with different Logins columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got Postgres table with text columns - **LOGIN** and **IP**. I need to find all matches where **IP** occured with only different **LOGIN** columns.

Here is an example of input data:

```
LOGIN    IP
A        127.0.0.1
A        127.0.0.1
B        127.0.0.2
C        127.0.0.1 // same as A
D        127.0.0.3
D        127.0.0.3
E        127.0.0.2 // same as B
```

Here is what I want in output:

```
LOGIN    IP
A        127.0.0.1
C        127.0.0.1
B        127.0.0.2
E        127.0.0.2
```

Can I do it with one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need *exists*

```
select distinct Login, IP
from t
where exists (
    select * from t t2
    where t2.ip = t.ip and t2.login != t.login
)
order by IP
```